# For loop only running once on array arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I'm trying to create a  basic for loop which will loop through the arguments of a function. There can be a variable number of arguments, so I am using the in-built 'arguments' object for this purpose. However, the for loop nested inside the function seems to stop after the first index of arguments.

I've read some similar queries on here which have suggested stating the variable in the for loop so that it is local to the function and not a global value, but this doesn't seem to have worked either.

```
  function tickets(){

  var change = 0;

  for(var j = 0;j < arguments.length; j++) {
    if (arguments[j] == 25) {
     return(change + 1);
   }
    else if(arguments[j] == 50) {
      return(change - 1);
    }
    else {
      return(change - 3);
    }
  }
}

console.log(tickets(25, 25 ,50, 25, 100))
```

I would expect the above code to log:

1
1
-1
1
-3

but instead it just returns 1, or whatever I change the first value in the list of arguments to. This seems really simple but has me scratching my head - any ideas?

Comment: Yes, that's the expected behavior of [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement.

Comment: Also, your function doesnt take any input arguments.

Comment: @AsnimPAnsari In JS, you don't have to define argument list in the function definition, the arguments are passed when invoking the function. `arguments` is a native object containing all the passed arguments.

Comment: @Teemu thanks. this was a new information for me

Comment: Maybe you should review how javascript functions work. You can do it here https://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html and also modify the examples on page and execute them.  console.log(tickets(25) + tickets(25) + tickets(50) + tickets(25) + tickets(100)); would do kind of what you expected. As @Teemu said return will 'return' the value and finish therefore the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well the function stops when it hits the first return, you must add all result in an array and return the array after the loop's end

```
 function tickets(){

  var change = 0;
  var responses = [];

  for(var j = 0;j < arguments.length; j++) {
    if (arguments[j] == 25) {
     responses.push((change + 1));
   }
    else if(arguments[j] == 50) {
      responses.push((change - 1));
    }
    else {
      responses.push((change - 3));
    }
  }

  return responses;
}

console.log(tickets(25, 25 ,50, 25, 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `return` so entire function is exited without going forward. There are many ways you can manage this situation - one being instead of return save the results and return at end as Mamun explained in answer or if you wish to do in fashion you are attempting you can use `map` for the same

```js
function tickets(){
  var change = 0;

  return Array.from(arguments).map((d,j) => {
    if (arguments[j] == 25) {
     return(change + 1);
   }
    else if(arguments[j] == 50) {
      return(change - 1);
    }
    else {
      return(change - 3);
    }
  })
}

console.log(tickets(25, 25 ,50, 25, 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't expect any arguments. 
You need to add a parameter to the function declaration. It's like a placeholder for the argument(s) you would like the function to take and deal with. In this case: 
function tickets(arguments){
}

I would suggest using arrays for both arguments list and results list.
So the function call would be :
tickets([25,25,50,25,100])

As other people suggested - you can use array.map(), array.reduce() or forEach() instead.

If for loop is mandatory for some reason, this is a possible answer:

```js
function tickets(arguments) {
  var result = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < arguments.length; j++) {
    var change = 0;
    if (arguments[j] == 25) {
      result.push(change + 1);
    } else if (arguments[j] == 50) {
      result.push(change - 1);
    } else {
      result.push(change - 3);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(tickets([25, 25, 50, 25, 100]));
```

Comment: This is incorrect answer, see [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56965999/for-loop-only-running-once-on-array-arguments#comment100469174_56965999).

Answer (score -1):

`return` exit function execution. In your case change every `return` to `console.log`